# Cypress cy.visit() failed trying to load

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

My cypress tests were running smoothly on a remote machine till last week.
Then, last week the execution time took too long (109 minutes ) and my test stage was get timeout by gitlab-ci.

*"There has been a timeout failure or the job got stuck. Check your timeout limits or try again"*

My tests were left unfinished because there was a timeout. After that day I couldn't access my usual baseUrl via this environment. I get "cy.visit() failed trying to load" error every time I run a test.

I think that unfinished test is still running in somewhere.. so I can't access that baseUrl again. How can I fix this situation? How can I terminate all my cypress tests by gitlab-ci?

Thanks..

Comment: Can you access the site manually?